# Word for "tongue clapping"

Tags: verbs, sounds

So there's this sound that sounds like "click" that you make if you move your tongue high up, bend it backward and then fastly hit floor of the mouth with it. I'm not even sure how it's called in my own language. If you repeat this sound many times in short amount of time it kinda sounds like a horse that is slowly walking on solid ground. Do you have any words for that sound in english?

Comment: Do you mean [tsk-tsk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsk%E2%80%93tsk)?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clop

Comment: I've always called it "clicking the tongue".

Comment: Must be a regional thing- since I know it as a tongue [cluck](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cluck), as opposed to tongue click.  But I guess both are valid.

Comment: I'm not sure that's common in English. In my experience the characteristic disapproval sound tsk-tsk is all done by sucking air between the tongue and roof of the mouth. Your sound would be much more of a clucking noise- I have a vague recollection of seeing something like that in movies - something to do with service people I think.

Comment: What is the sound of one tongue clapping?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Answer (score 1):

"Tongue clap" is correct; tsk, click and clap are all in this category. North American pediatricians use it when describing a child's development to new parents (the doctor even made the sounds you describe as was my experience with my 1st born) and also in diagnosing autism (as was my adopted-sisters experience with her 1st born).